# backup reg hives

Tags: c++, visual-c++, backup, registry

Using http://support.microsoft.com/kb/240184 I'm able to open SAM, SOFTWARE, SYSTEM reg hives, but I do not know the next step to get them copied in a different backup folder? I get Access Denied when I try to use BackupRead API. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`BackupRead` is not a magical function that lets you read any file. For starters, you need to run as a user with backup privilege. Secondly, you must respect the `FilesNotToBackup` registry key. You also have to call `CreateFile` with `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS`. But even with that in mind, I'm not sure if it's the bets way to backup the registry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm aware of all that but still can't copy these files. I know for sure that there is a way, because there are many programs doing that - just have to learn more about security of the objects...